# How to train model by google's object detection with multi gpu in one machine

Tags: tensorflow

How to train model by google's object detection with multi gpu in one machine. I set the param as follow:

```
master = ''
task = 0
num_clones = 2
clone_on_cpu = False
worker_replicas = 1
ps_tasks = 0
```

but i get an error in File "\tensorflow\models\object_detection\trainer.py", line 122, in

```
_create_losses

_get_inputs(input_queue, detection_model.num_classes)

Value Error: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set batch_size=2 <- .config

Answer (score 0):

You can set the num_clones (the number of gpus you want to use) and the ps_tasks (parameter server) parameter

`python3 train.py  --logtostderr  \
    --pipeline_config_path=model/ssd_inception_v2.config \
    --train_dir=model/train \
    --num_clones=2 --ps_tasks=1`